# Extinction of the population - Branching process with separate generations

Tags: probability

> Consider a branching process with separate generations and it is
>   assumed that each individual of each generation, independently of the
>   others, produces a number of individuals of the next generation
>   according to a binomial distribution with parameter $3$ and $1/2$.
>
> At the initial generation, there are two individuals. Did you certain
>   extinction of the population? Otherwise, what is the probability of
>   extinction of the population?

In this problem, what is meant by a branching process with separate generations?

Comment: I believe it just means that the generations are stochastically independent (the usual assumption in a Galton-Watson process). Where is this question from? Is there any mention of "separate generations" in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offspring distribution has generating function
$$P(s) = \frac18 + \frac38 s + \frac38 s^2 + \frac18 s^3 = \frac18(1+s)^3, $$
and mean
$$\mu = P'(1) = \frac32>1, $$
so if the initial generation had one individual, the probability of extinction is the unique solution to $P(\pi)=\pi$ with $0<\pi<1$, in which case $\pi=2-\sqrt3$. Now, since the initial generation has two individuals, we can treat these as two separate processes, and extinction occurs exactly when both processes expire. Hence the extinction probability is
$$(2-\sqrt 3)^2=7-4\sqrt3\approx 0.0718. $$

Comment: This is the solution I found!